# Set focus after a particular item in an inputbox in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So lets say I have an input box that looks something like this:

```
<input id="fuzzyname" value="" placeholder="&Fuzzybear">
```

I want to use javascript/JQuery so that when I click in that input box it will put the cursor after the & and the placeholder becomes the value in the input box.

This is kind of what I have so far:

```
$("#fuzzyname").focus(function () {
       var value = $(this).attr("placeholder");
       var symbol = "&";
       var cursorIndex = value.indexOf(symbol);
       //This is where I want to output the value into the inputbox with the cursor after cursorIndex 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cursorIndex = value.indexOf(symbol) + 1;
$(this).val(value);
this.setSelectionRange(cursorIndex, cursorIndex);
```

Comment: AHH .setSelectionRange was what I was looking for. Thanks so much.